# Problem while installing ADT on eclipse galileo (ubuntu)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I have eclipse Galileo installed my ubuntu machine. It was working fine with Android 2.2 ADT.
But in between something happened and I was not able to run any program. So I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled. Now When I try to installed ADT, it is giving errors.
Help -> Install new  packages ->
Work With (add)
Name :ADT.
Location:http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
It is listing ->Developing tool.
I selected it and pressed 'Next'
It is giving following error.

```
The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found.
```

Please help me to install ADT on eclipse.

Comment: You can also check this [link](http://marleine.blogspot.com/2011/10/installing-android-development-tools.html) for solving this issue in other eclipse versions: [Installing Android Development Tools (ADT) in Eclipse Error](http://marleine.blogspot.com/2011/10/installing-android-development-tools.html)

Comment: Try it,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520230/error-while-updating-adt-23-0-0-in-eclipse/24521930#24521930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it and if it works:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/cannot-complete-install-because-one-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to ****window>>Preferences>>android** and proper sdk location is given or not.. and then click apply..

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Site dialog, click Archive.
4. Browse and select the downloaded zip file.
5. Enter a name for the local update site (e.g., "Android Plugin") in the "Name" field.
6. Click OK.

If it will not work then give ADT plugin location directly from internet.