# Error while updating ADT 23.0.0 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I already have gone through this question but it didn't helped.
**[Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)**

While starting eclipse it shows below error.

[image]

When I tried with Check for updates - it does nothing.

Then I tried

Help -> Install New Software -> "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

It shows below error

```
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
    Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.feature.group 23.0.1.1256982)
  Software currently installed: Android Native Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT CDT Integration 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk 23.0.1.1256982)
    ADT CDT Integration 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Native Development Tools 23.0.1.1256982 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.feature.group 23.0.1.1256982)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk [23.0.1.1256982]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Native Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
```

Can anyone help me for this. Thank you.

Comment: uninstall all the ADB tool, reinstall.

Comment: Agreed with panini. I usually do a clean install of eclipse and then reference it to my workspace.

Comment: Possible conflict with - [This Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in ADT 23 Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445367/error-in-adt-23-update)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved!

Go to help--about eclipse
Uninstall DDMS,ADT etc
Go to install new software and using the link install them:- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Worked fine for me :)

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey, Use this link using install new software in ADT.

Comment: i got that y it is coming (error with your link )put "/" at the end of the link

Comment: what the hell is "etc". You mean uninstall everything? You are not being helpful and look like you're just looking for rep.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback to adt22.6.2, Just replace the tools folder in android sdk.

This is a packaging bug. The entire proguard file is missing. We'll have an update asap, but until then just copy it over from a previous version of the tools:

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip

So at the end if you started from a new ADT copy by hand the files :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem, as nothing was working for me, I simply replaced the entire adt base folder with earlier version (which i installed initially), so now started afresh

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, was able to solve in this way -

1. Eclipse-->Help-->About Eclipse---->Installation Details
2. Select - Android DDMS, ADT, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Native Development Tools, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES packages. All must be version 22.xx
3. Uninstall all the plugins selected above.
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Install ADT from update site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Uninstall button grayed out

Answer (score 1):

Adding just an extra bit of information as none of the above solutions worked for me (**except for the replacement one**)

I just went to

> sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86 (32bit)

Copied configuration, Features and plugins folders and pasted it in ADT\eclipse folder choose **skip** where it asks to replace and rest will be fine, no need to replace the entire thing

done

once you start eclipse it will ask you for SDK location, provide the location and continue

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem yesterday, I tried the above solution but it was still not working properly. I was facing some errors and difficulty.

So I **re-installed Eclipse** Luna and then did the following :

- Help -> Install New Software
- Add  -> Name : ADT Plugin
- Url  -> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Download and Install the Plugin and then Update the API's using SDK Manager.
Now I recommend to use **Android Studio** though.